# How to find the tangent to any pixel?

Tags: c#-4.0, graphics, vector-graphics

I want to find tangent at each pixel in image. 
NOTE: image is having white background and shape border color is block.

What i did is, 
Algo

```
While(true)
     take pixel 
     if pixel color is black 
           make 3 X 3 matrix => fill the matrix by surrounding pixel color
            ...means assume white =0 and black=1 then keeping selected pixel 
           at center for 3 X 3 matrix and finding all other value;
           ----------------------------here i want to find tangent line to selected pixel;
     end if
     Move to next pixel.
End  while
```

Please help Exams on head .

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably a [Sobel Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). It's implemented as a convolution of the neighborhood around a pixel with the matrix:

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

and again with:

```
-1 -2 -1
 0  0  0
 1  2  1
```

Call the results of the 2 convolutions x and y, respectively. Once you have them, you can get the magnitude of the gradient by taking the square root of the sum of the squares:

```
mag = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

and the direction of the gradient (which should be tangent to the pixel you're examining) by taking the arctangent of y over x:

```
tangent = atan2(y / x)
```

Comment: This is working but i am not getting exact tangent of each point. .  . . but thank you for your time and guidance.........
Is there any other best algorithm or modified version of sobel edge detection algorithm ?............... @user1118321

Comment: i have found 5 X 5 matrix of sobel http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~image529/TA529/Image529_99/assignments/edge_detection/references/sobel.htm  ........... If i use 5 X 5 matrix then will i get exact tangent?